# Вывод ответа ajax-запроса на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, dom

Сам запрос:

```
var gender ='Male';
      $.ajax({
        url: '/main/main/public/go/' + gender,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
          console.log(data);


        },
      });
```

Ответ приходит такой:

> `{id: 4, name: "admin", email: "mort@gmail.com"}`

Каким образом можно обратиться к данным и вывести на HTML страницу?

Answer (score 3):

Заменить

```
console.log(data);
```

на

```
document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: А каким образом обратиться к конкретному свойству? Например id?

Comment: document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(data).id;

Comment: А если запрос выдал несколько [{"name":"admin","avatar":"avatardefault.jpg","id":4},{"name":"Maria","avatar":"avatardefault.jpg","id":6}] , То как обратиться к конкретному объекту? И какому либо его свойству?

Comment: И как именно можно вывести в цикле каждый объект со всеми свойствами в DOM?